# load external html into div - jquery in external file not called in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, load, external

I've been going round and round in circles with this...! I'm new to jQuery. I have an accordion (jquery.accordion.js) and I want the content that's revealed when you click one of the accordion bars to animate into view. Ideally I'd like this animated content to be loaded in from an external file. So, I have my accordion page (the parent), which loads the external HTML (the child) like so:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" onClick="$('#content').load('external.html');">Education<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
    <div class="st-content">
      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

In the external page there are 2 divs (essentially a picture and some text) that should animate, for which I have the following:

```
<div id="screenshot">An image....</div>
<div id="contenttext"><p>Some text...</p></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
      $("#screenshot").hide().delay(80).fadeIn(500);
      $("#screenshot").hide().delay(500).animate({'opacity': 'toggle', 'margin-top': '10px'}, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
      $("#contenttext").delay(200).animate({'margin-left': '520px'}, 500, "easeOutExpo");
    });
  An });
</script>
```

Everything is working fine locally, and FF and Chrome work online, but in IE10 online the external html loads, but nothing animates! I'm guessing this is because in the external html I haven't specified a source for the jQuery, and even though FF and Chrome use the jQuery already loaded into the parent accordion page, IE is unable to for some reason. If I do specify a source in the external html, however, the animation breaks in FF and Chrome but fixes IE! I've also tried adding the animation to the accordion js and got it working for IE and FF online but not Chrome! AAAAARGGHH! I don't mind that much if the content ends up not being external, I just want it to work for FF, Chrome and IE. Please please help!!

[Click here to see online](http://www.ikonoklast.co.uk/testfolder/indextest.html) and click the 'Education' line in the accordion

Many thanks for taking the time.

Chris

Comment: The Javascript is inside `$(document).ready()`. That only executes when the original page is loaded, not when you load Javascript dynamically.

Comment: jQuery's `load` function strips script tags. This is documented: http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution. You need to set up events and animation in the 'parent' document.